# Is synchronized "deep" in java?

Tags: java, object, synchronization

Lets say you have:

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar b;
}
public class Bar {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

And then you call:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
....
synchronized(f) {
   f.b.x = 3;
   f.b.y = 5; //x and y must be adjacent primes at all times.
}
```

If our thread-safeness deep? i.e. does synchronized(f) prevent another thread (inside it's own synchronized(f) block) from seeing f.b while f.b is updated? What about using synchronized(this) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking whether synchronization is "deep" shows that you don't yet fully understand how Java thread "synchronization" works. All beginning Java programmers usually have the same misconception -- "synchronizing on `f` makes access to `f`'s fields thread-safe". This is *not* true.

When one thread is executing your `synchronized(f)` block, no other thread can enter any block or method `synchronized` on the same object. **THAT IS ALL.**

There is no reason why you must protect the mutable fields of `f` by synchronizing on `f`. You can synchronize on any Object at all you want, as long as you always use the same one, and as long as you always synchronize when you are accessing/modifying the fields of `f`.

Conversely, synchronizing on `f` does NOT mean that your access of `f`'s fields is necessarily thread-safe. You could have some other code elsewhere in the program, modifying `f`'s fields without any synchronization at all, or synchronizing on a different Object.

If this seems confusing, that's because it is. The designers of Java made a bad choice (to associate an implicit mutex with each and every object), and we just have to deal with it.

Comment: why was it a bad choice? (curious). by way of a succinct explanation that would fit in a comment, i'd suggest pointing to a similar language or library that made a better choice. PS: hopefully you are aware of the latest and greatest concurrency features in Java. `synchronized` is rather archaic.

Comment: i guess you probably mean the choice to allow any and all objects to be used as locks for any arbitrary code, in addition to whatever the object's core function in the program.

Comment: @randomstring, it would have been better to use explicit mutex objects from the beginning, like Ruby's `Mutex` class. This would have been far less confusing, and Java implementations would not have to make a choice between high locking performance and low per-object memory footprint. It would still be possible to have `synchronized` methods if desired -- these would just be syntactic sugar for locking/unlocking a `Mutex` object held in a private field.

Answer (score 6):

Not at all.

The `synchronized` keyword only affects other synchronized blocks around the same object.
It has nothing to do with the object itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry, changed the question to clarify this issue.

Comment: @KevinKostlan: Other threads inside `synchronized(f)` will wait for the current block to finish, no matter what it does.  Threads not inside `synchronized(f)` are not affected at all.